# why the last element of array changed after 2 foreach loop?

Tags: php, arrays

what's the magic?
the last element of $data changed, after 2 for each loop.

```
<?php
$data = array("1" => "a", "2" => "b");
print_r($data);
foreach($data as $k=>&$v) {}
foreach($data as $k=>$v) {}
print_r($data);
```

output:[2] => a after the second foreach

```
Array
(
    [1] => a
    [2] => b
)
Array
(
    [1] => a
    [2] => a
)
```

it the code change to this,the array won't change:

```
<?php
foreach($data as $k=>&$v) {}
foreach($data as $k=>&$v) {}
```

Comment: Because `&v`. Reference of `$v` and the last array element remain even after the foreach loop. It is recommended to destroy it by `unset()`.

Comment: i can't understand,why the reference changed the original array? i do nothing with that reference

Answer (score 6, accepted):

From the [foreach](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php) manual:

> **Warning** Reference of a $value and the last array element remain even
>   after the foreach loop. It is recommended to destroy it by unset().

So at the end of the first `foreach`, `$v` is a reference to the last element in the array.  The next `foreach`'s first iteration changes the value of `$v` (to the value of the first array element) which is a reference to the last element in the array, so it is changed.

```
$data = array("1" => "a", "2" => "b");
print_r($data);
foreach($data as $k=>&$v) {}
unset($v);                     // *** UNSET HERE ***
foreach($data as $k=>$v) {}
print_r($data);
```

Result:

```
Array
(
    [1] => a
    [2] => b
)
Array
(
    [1] => a
    [2] => b
)
```

Comment: why the Reference of a $value changed the $data?i do not do anything with this reference

Comment: Yes you do. Or rather your second foreach loop does. It assigns a new value to `$v` which is still referencing the last array element.

Comment: Yes, thanks @ThiefMaster, I added a description.